Using PG service definition with `create_engine()` from SQLAlchem 2.0+
psycopg is nice, because it can directly make use the database' credentials from the pg_service.conf file:
import psycopg

psycopg.__version__
>>> '3.2.1'

psycopg.connect(service='myservice')
>>> <psycopg.Connection [IDLE] (host=myhost port=5432 user=myuser database=mydatabase) at 0x769e731a3170>

How could I use the same service definition with create_engine() from SQLAlchemy 2.0+?
I cannot find any documentation about using a PostgreSQL service here:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#postgresql

It's still possible to use the connection URL with query parameters as follow to take benefit from an existing pg service definition:
import sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy.__version__
>>> '2.0.34'

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

config = dict(
    drivername="postgresql+psycopg",
    query={"service": "myservice"},
)

url = URL.create(**config)
engine = create_engine(url)

And then use the engine as usual.
This was inspired by this GitHub issue: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4601
